# Android: Flurry Dashboard is not showing Data

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

All,

I am using Flurry in one of my android app for analytics. I created a account on Flurry Portal and got API Key. I followed the steps provided on 'How to start with flurry' document. When I started application and checked logs, it says flurry is capturing events and sending data. But I can not see anything on Flurry Portal. Here is my code

Application

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application{

    private static Bus instance = null;

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = new Bus();


        FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
        FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(true);
        FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.INFO);
        FlurryAgent.init(this,"XXXXXXXXXXX");
        Log.i("FLURRY AGENT", "Initialized Flurry Agent");
    }
}
```

For logging Events

```
FlurryAgent.logEvent(getString(R.string.filter_listing_event));
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
```

Here are the logs

```
08-17 15:28:24.651 17864-17864/? W/FlurryAgent: 'setLogEnabled' method is deprecated.
08-17 15:28:24.651 17864-17864/? W/FlurryAgent: 'setLogLevel' method is deprecated.
08-17 15:28:24.671 17864-17878/? E/FlurryAgent: GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES EXCEPTION: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil
08-17 15:28:24.671 17864-17878/? E/FlurryAgent: There is a problem with the Google Play Services library, which is required for Android Advertising ID support. The Google Play Services library should be integrated in any app shipping in the Play Store that uses analytics or advertising.
08-17 15:28:24.681 17864-17864/? W/FlurryAgent: 'init' method is deprecated.
08-17 15:28:24.681 17864-17864/? I/FLURRY AGENT: Initialized FLurry Agent
08-17 15:28:24.681 17864-17878/? I/FlurryAgent: New main file also not found. returning..
08-17 15:28:24.871 17864-17878/? W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session started for context:com.test.activity.SplashActivity@6859dd
08-17 15:28:24.871 17864-17878/? W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session resumed for context:com.test.activity.SplashActivity@6859dd
08-17 15:28:24.871 17864-17878/? E/FlurryAgent: GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES EXCEPTION: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil
08-17 15:28:24.871 17864-17878/? E/FlurryAgent: There is a problem with the Google Play Services library, which is required for Android Advertising ID support. The Google Play Services library should be integrated in any app shipping in the Play Store that uses analytics or advertising.
08-17 15:28:24.891 17864-17878/? W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.test/files/.YFlurrySenderIndex.info.AnalyticsMain
08-17 15:28:26.281 17864-17889/com.test W/FlurryAgent: Analytics report sent.
```

Last line in logs shows analytics are sent. But still I cant see anything on flurry portal.

Answer (score 0):

This was also happening to me. I did two things:

- Updated the Flurry SDK to version 6.4.2
- Used `FlurryAgent.Builder` to initialize flurry

See here: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/android/